# Laravel/Lumen 5.3: How to set separate database user configuration on migrations

Tags: php, laravel, database-schema, database-migration, lumen

Generally, letting application to change database schema is not a good idea (at least from some dbas point of view!)

So is there any workaround to use separate database user *which has enough schema update privileges* for `php artisan migrate` command?

Answer (score 1):

You can always set the connection on migration.
for example:

```
Schema::connection('myotherconnection')->create('some_table', function($table)
{
     $table->increments('id'):
});
```

Comment: At first it looks fine, but still developer has access to both connections